# Postfix logs (simple relay server)

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to setup Postfix as a simply relay server (relay all mail from localhost via my ISP). I can connect to Postfix and send the email, but it never arrives at the destination.

How do I know what went wrong? All the folders in /var/spool/postfix are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Just found my own answer, log files are in `/var/log/mail.*`